# preventDefault on anchor tag with tel: doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on a telephone number it should do nothing on desktop and on mobile it should call the number. I thought the solution would be as simple as returning false or preventDefault when on a desktop but so far it doesnt seem to work:

```
<a href="tel:555555">555-555</a>
```

I'm using `mouseup()` so that it only prevents it on desktop. The function runs but the browser still tries to open up another app.

```
$('a[href^="tel"]').mouseup(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```

Is there a solution as simple as this that actually works or is the best method to detect for mobile and change the **href** attributes as seen on other questions?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the answer below. `mouseup()` runs but can't preventDefault. This was the final code using modernizr:

```
$('a[href^="tel"]').on('click',function (e) {
    if ($("html").hasClass("no-touch")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
function callMethod(){
  //do stuff here
}
$('a[href^="tel"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    callMethod();
})

$('a[href^="tel"]').on('touchstart',function (e) {
    callMethod();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$('.no-touch a[href^="tel"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you need it to work on touch devices, and are using Modernizr (which it looks like) you could do this instead:

```
$('a[href^="tel"]').on('click',function (e) {

   if (!Modernizr.touch) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }

    ... my touch code ...
});
```

Comment: Aah yeah could totally do that. A little cleaner.

Comment: @DustinSilk, With this method to you need to use another function for mobile device..

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Well if it is touch enabled then we don't preventDefault and it continues as normal calling the external Phone app from the href.  Click events fire on both touch and desktop devices